# a peculiar issue regarding exporting data in R

Tags: r

I typically use R to manage large amounts of data.  I am in the process of generating a large number of datasets to be processed by another software. This software can only read numeric.  In the data I have an empty column "C"(class is numeric) which I use in the software to ignore the first row of the data which has variable names. My software is not able to process the data when I export it into a .csv file from R. However, the software is able to process the data if I save the exported dataset (in .csv format) after deleting the first cell(nothing is there in this cell) under the column "C" then drag it to end of the data.It is painful to open thousands of datasets to do this.I am suspecting that the problem is with R . Have any of you had problem like this? Appreciate you help.

I am using the read.table function to read the dataset and after making the required changes using the write.csv function to write the dataset.

"

```
   C  ID   IDV    DV 
        1    0.25    0
        1    0.5    27
        1    1      30
        2    0.25    0
        2    0.5    34
        2    1      43        "
```

The column "C" is an empty column only used to ignore the first row of the data (IGNORE=C)because the software cannot process letters in the dataset. Also, in the instructions I give the software I indicate that the first column is ID, second column is IDV and third column is DV and so on.

Comment: Could you please show the first four or five rows of a real `.csv` file generated as you are doing it?  I am not sure I understand what the problem is.

Comment: You have a choice in write.csv to omit the header. Why aren't you doing so?

Comment: when doing `write.csv`  you can do `write.csv(whatever,"whatever.csv",row.names=FALSE)` . May be this will do.

Comment: Both row and column names false: `write.csv(whatever,"whatever.csv",row.names=FALSE, col.names = FALSE)`, and don't bother with your blank `C` column.

Comment: @ Bonded dust : I am getting the following message: attempt to set 'col.names' ignored
 when I attempt to remove the header with col.names=F

Comment: @Gregor : I am getting this message "attempt to set 'col.names' ignored"

Comment: Hmm, maybe you'll have to use `write.table` then: `write.table(x = your_df, file = "whatever.csv", row.names = F, col.names = F, sep = ",")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `write.csv` won't let you remove column headers, but `write.table` will. As long as we specify `sep = ","`, the output file will be a CSV:

```
write.table(x = your_df, file = "whatever.csv",
            row.names = F, col.names = F, sep = ",")
```